# C# mysql example Command.ExecuteReader throws exception

Tags: c#, mysql

I am writing a segment of C# code to get some data from mysql database. I have started with ready-made example but it gave me an error at `rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()`

A screen Shot of the thrown exception is shown below as well

[image: exception thrown screenshot]

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; 

public class Program
{

    static void Main() 
    {
            string serverName = "192.168.0.012";
            string port = "1234";
            string db = "cust_db";
            string userID = "root";
            string password = "pass";
            string cs = "Server=" + serverName + ";Port=" + port + ";Database=" + db + ";Uid=" + userID + ";password=" + password;


        MySqlConnection conn = null;
        MySqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try 
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            conn.Open();

            string stm = "SELECT * FROM cust_tb";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read()) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetInt32(0) + ": " 
                    + rdr.GetString(1));
            }

        } catch (MySqlException ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}",  ex.ToString());

        } finally 
        {
            if (rdr != null) 
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }

            if (conn != null) 
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}


at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetChararcterSet(DBVersion version, String CharSetName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetFieldMetaData41()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetFieldMetaData()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnMetadata(Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Program.Main() in c:\Users\omran.alhammadi\Desktop\csMysqlConnection\csMysqlConnection\Program.cs:line 28
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetChararcterSet(DBVersion version, String CharSetName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetFieldMetaData41()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetFieldMetaData()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnMetadata(Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Program.Main() in c:\Users\omran.alhammadi\Desktop\csMysqlConnection\csMysqlConnection\Program.cs:line 28
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
The program '[17084] csMysqlConnection.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: what line is the exception thrown on?

Comment: at rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Comment: can you show more of the exception details, such as the stack trace?

Comment: I edited the post to show the stack trace

Comment: There is a similar post [Here][1]. You may get solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972337/system-collections-generic-keynotfoundexception-the-given-key-was-not-present-i

Comment: is the problem with vs 2012 or with the mysql db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been having this problem and I did some research. After a while, I just fixed this problem.

My problem was the database table encoding. I had `utf32_unicode_ci`, and I changed it to `utf8_unicode_ci`. It works perfectly now.

Hope you have some luck on it.